# Angular async pipe in combination with Router shows different behavior in build for development and in build for production

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-routing

I have a very simple test app made of 2 components

- **AppComponent**
- **ListComponent**

Both components have the same behavior: at load time they show a list of items coming from an Observable using async pipe. **AppComponent** in addition has a button and a RouterOutlet where it loads **ListComponent** as soon as the button is clicked.

When this code is compiled for development, i.e. with `ng build`, everything works as expected. When the same code is compiled for prod, i.e. `ng build --prod`, then the behavior is different. In this second case, if I click the button to go to **ListComponent**, the Observable of **ListComponent** DOES NOT EMIT anymore at the load of the page.

The code is the following (I have also [a Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yxkdq1?file=src%2Fmain.ts) where the problem though does not occur)

**ListComponent**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  template: `
    <input #searchField type="text">
    <div *ngFor="let item of itemsToShow$ | async">{{item}}</div>
  `,
})
export class ListComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit  {
  @ViewChild('searchField', {static: true}) searchField: ElementRef;
  search$: Observable<string>;
  itemsToShow$: Observable<string[]>;

  ngOnInit() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.search$ = merge(concat(of(''), fromEvent(this.searchField.nativeElement, 'keyup'))).pipe(
      map(() => this.searchField.nativeElement.value)
    );

    this.itemsToShow$ = this.itemsToShow();
  }

  itemsToShow() {
    let itemAsLocalVar: string[];
    return of(ITEMS).pipe(
      delay(10),
      tap(items => itemAsLocalVar = items),
      switchMap(() => combineLatest([this.search$])),
      map(([searchFilter]) => itemAsLocalVar.filter(i => i.includes(searchFilter))),
    );
  }
}
```

**AppComponent**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <input #searchField type="text">
    <div *ngFor="let item of itemsToShow$ | async">{{item}}</div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <button (click)="goToList()">List</button>
  `
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit  {
  @ViewChild('searchField', {static: true}) searchField: ElementRef;
  search$: Observable<string>;
  itemsToShow$: Observable<string[]>;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.search$ = merge(concat(
       of(''), 
       fromEvent(this.searchField.nativeElement, 'keyup')
     )).pipe(
       map(() => this.searchField.nativeElement.value)
     );
    this.itemsToShow$ = this.itemsToShow();
  }
  itemsToShow() {
    let itemAsLocalVar: string[];
    return of(ITEMS).pipe(
      delay(10),
      tap(items => itemAsLocalVar = items),
      switchMap(() => {
        return combineLatest([this.search$]);
      }),
      map(([searchFilter]) => itemAsLocalVar.filter(i => i.includes(searchFilter))),
      tap(i => console.log(i))
    );
  }
  goToList() {
    this.router.navigate(['list']);
  }
}
```

Any idea of what is going wrong is very much appreciated.

Any idea of

Comment: which version ?

Comment: Angular 7 and 8

Answer (score 1):

A strange/weird behaviour but good that you posted this issue/question.

I think the issue in production mode is happening because the way change detection works in production vs development mode [https://blog.angularindepth.com/a-gentle-introduction-into-change-detection-in-angular-33f9ffff6f10].

In development mode, change detection runs two times just to be sure [because of that you might have seen `Expression changed.....` exception [https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4]. 
Please also notice that you are setting up your observables in `ngAfterViewInit`.
Because of 2 cycles of change detection, in dev mode, you see that `ListComponent` renders correctly. After the first cycle of change detection, you have assigned the observable in `ngAfterViewInit` which is detected in the 2nd change detection cycle and component rendered as expected.

In production mode change detection does not run two times. It runs only one time due to enhance performance. Your `ListComponent` will render list if you click the "List" button again [after very first click] because clicking of the button runs Angular change detection.

To fix this you have the following options -

**1.** Force the change detection by injecting:

```
constructor(private _cdref: ChangeDetectorRef) {

  }
```

and change your `ngAfterViewInit()` like this

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.search$ = merge(concat(of(''), fromEvent(this.searchField.nativeElement, 'keyup'))).pipe(
      map(() => this.searchField.nativeElement.value)
    );
    this.itemsToShow$ = this.itemsToShow();
    this._cdref.detectChanges();
  }
```

**2.** Move your `ngAfterViewInit()` code to `ngOnInit()` like this:

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.search$ = merge(concat(of(''), fromEvent(this.searchField.nativeElement, 'keyup'))).pipe(
      map(() => this.searchField.nativeElement.value)
    );
    this.itemsToShow$ = this.itemsToShow();

  }
```

I would recommend going for option 2.

Comment: I agree with that the issue has to do with Change Detection run differently in dev and prod mode. The strange thing though is that this behavior occurs only in combination with the Router. If you go straight to the ListComponent with the url `myserver/list` then the async pipe subscribes to the Observable and the list is shown immediately at load time. As per moving the logic to `ngOnInit` this is not possible, since the Observable pipe uses `this.search$` which relies on an element ref set via `@ViewChild` whose result is not available in `ngOnInit` but rather in `ngAfterViewInit`.

Comment: @Picci did you try it to move your code to ‘ngOnInit’ . I would request you to try. It worked absolutely fine. I had tested before giving my answer.

Comment: Moving to ngOnInit will setup the observables it will not be executed until next rendering cycle [via async pipe].

Comment: You are right, I can move the logic to ngOnInit. Still the behavior is quite weird. Thanks anyways